C# Unity Bug with blocks disappearing for no reason
I am following a tutorial on how to make a Block Puzzle game: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfCwLjfroMs&list=PL17UdFXqPr_cFumTzS4PvIc1mhW79umG8&index=13
Everything works fine besides the issue that some other people had beside me.
Here is the issue: for some reason every other time I spawn new blocks, if you move the middle or left side first, the block on the right also disappears. Every other time the block remains.
Some people have pointed out that it maybe because the blocks do not return to their original position, therefore when I place the middle block first it checks that the block on the right is not on the original position, therefore it deactivates it...
I have tried the solutions that other people presented, but they didn't work. Then I have tried to figure it out by myself, but after 2 hours of debugging I think I have managed to break it even more :). I am not sure if the question fits this sites requirements and style, but if someone has any ideas how to fix this it would be great to hear from you!
Before:

After:

The code that you potentially will need (deleted the parts that you won't probably need):
Shape:
public class Shape : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IBeginDragHandler, 
IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IPointerDownHandler
{
    public GameObject squareShapeImage;
    public Vector3 shapeSelectedScale;
    public Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0f, 700f);

    [HideInInspector]
    public ShapeData CurrentShapeData;

    public int TotalSquareNumber { get; set; }

    private List<GameObject> _currentShape = new List<GameObject>();
    private Vector3 _shapeStartScale;
    private RectTransform _transform;
    private bool _shapeDraggable = true;
    private Canvas _canvas;
    private Vector3 _startPosition;
    private bool _shapeActive = true;

    public void Awake()
    {
        _shapeStartScale = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale;
        _transform = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        _canvas = GetComponentInParent<Canvas>();
        _shapeDraggable = true;
        _startPosition = _transform.localPosition;
        _shapeActive = true;
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        GameEvents.MoveShapeToStartPosition += MoveShapeToStartPosition;
        GameEvents.SetShapeInactive += SetShapeInactive;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        GameEvents.MoveShapeToStartPosition -= MoveShapeToStartPosition;
        GameEvents.SetShapeInactive -= SetShapeInactive;

    }

    public bool IsOnStartPosition()
    {
        return _transform.localPosition == _startPosition;
    }

    public bool IsAnyOfShapeSquareActive()
    {
        foreach (var square in _currentShape)
        {
            if (square.gameObject.activeSelf)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void DeactivateShape()
    {
        if (_shapeActive)
        {
            foreach (var square in _currentShape)
            {
                square?.GetComponent<ShapeSquare>().DeactivateShape();
            }
        }

        _shapeActive = false;
    }

    private void SetShapeInactive()
    {
        if (IsOnStartPosition() == false && IsAnyOfShapeSquareActive())
        {
            foreach (var square in _currentShape)
            {
                square.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ActivateShape()
    {
        if (!_shapeActive)
        {
            foreach (var square in _currentShape)
            {
                square?.GetComponent<ShapeSquare>().ActivateShape();
            }
        }

        _shapeActive = true;
    }

    public void RequestNewShape(ShapeData shapeData)
    {
        _transform.localPosition = _startPosition;
        CreateShape(shapeData);
    }

    public void CreateShape(ShapeData shapeData)
    {
        CurrentShapeData = shapeData;
        TotalSquareNumber = GetNumberOfSquares(shapeData);

        while (_currentShape.Count <= TotalSquareNumber)
        {
            _currentShape.Add(Instantiate(squareShapeImage, transform) as GameObject);
        }

        foreach (var square in _currentShape)
        {
            square.gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.zero;
            square.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

        var squareRect = squareShapeImage.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        var moveDistance = new Vector2(squareRect.rect.width * squareRect.localScale.x,
            squareRect.rect.height * squareRect.localScale.y);
        int currentIndexInList = 0;

        // set positions to form a final shape
        for (var row = 0; row < shapeData.rows; row++)
        {
            for (var column = 0; column < shapeData.columns; column++)
            {
                if (shapeData.board[row].column[column])
                {
                    _currentShape[currentIndexInList].SetActive(true);
                    _currentShape[currentIndexInList].GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition =
                    new Vector2(GetXPositionForShapeSquare(shapeData, column, moveDistance), GetYPositionForShapeSquare(shapeData, row, moveDistance));

                    currentIndexInList++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        this.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = shapeSelectedScale;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        _transform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
        _transform.anchorMax = new Vector2(0, 0);
        _transform.pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);

        Vector2 pos;
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(_canvas.transform as RectTransform,
            eventData.position, Camera.main, out pos);
        _transform.localPosition = pos + offset;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        this.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localScale = _shapeStartScale;
        GameEvents.CheckIfShapeCanBePlaced();
    }


    public void MoveShapeToStartPosition()
    {
        _transform.transform.localPosition = _startPosition;
    }
}

Grid:
public class Grid : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ShapeStorage shapeStorage;
    public int columns = 0;
    public int rows = 0;
    public float squaresGap = 0.1f;
    public GameObject gridSquare;
    public Vector2 startPosition = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    public float squareScale = 0.5f;
    public float everySquareOffset = 0.0f;

    private Vector2 _offset = new Vector2(0.0f, 0.0f);
    private List<GameObject> _gridSquares = new List<GameObject>();

    private void CheckIfShapeCanBePlaced()
    {
        var squareIndexes = new List<int>();

        foreach (var square in _gridSquares)
        {
            var gridSquare = square.GetComponent<GridSquare>();

            if (gridSquare.Selected && !gridSquare.SquareOccupied)
            {
                squareIndexes.Add(gridSquare.SquareIndex);
                gridSquare.Selected = false;
                //gridSquare.ActivateSquare();
            }
        }

        var currentSelectedShape = shapeStorage.GetCurrentSelectedShape();
        if (currentSelectedShape == null) return; //There is no selected shape;

        if (currentSelectedShape.TotalSquareNumber == squareIndexes.Count)
        {
            foreach (var squareIndex in squareIndexes)
            {
                _gridSquares[squareIndex].GetComponent<GridSquare>().PlaceShapeOnBoard();
            }

            var shapeLeft = 0;

            foreach (var shape in shapeStorage.shapeList)
            {
                if (shape.IsOnStartPosition() && shape.IsAnyOfShapeSquareActive())
                {
                    shapeLeft++;
                }
            }

            var counter = shapeLeft;

            if (shapeLeft == 0)
            {
                GameEvents.RequestNewShapes();
            }
            else 
            {
                GameEvents.SetShapeInactive();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            GameEvents.MoveShapeToStartPosition();
        }
    }
}

GameEvents:
public class GameEvents : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Action CheckIfShapeCanBePlaced;
    public static Action MoveShapeToStartPosition;
    public static Action RequestNewShapes;
    public static Action SetShapeInactive;
}

ShapeStorage:
public class ShapeStorage : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<ShapeData> shapeData;
    public List<Shape> shapeList;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        GameEvents.RequestNewShapes += RequestNewShapes;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        GameEvents.RequestNewShapes -= RequestNewShapes;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        foreach(var shape in shapeList)
        {
            var shapeIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, shapeData.Count);
            shape.CreateShape(shapeData[shapeIndex]);
        }        
    }

    public Shape GetCurrentSelectedShape()
    {
        foreach (var shape in shapeList)
        {
            if (shape.IsOnStartPosition() == false && shape.IsAnyOfShapeSquareActive())
            {
                return shape;
            }
        }

        Debug.LogError("No shape selected");
        return null;
    }

    private void RequestNewShapes()
    {
        foreach (var shape in shapeList)
        {
            var shapeIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, shapeData.Count); // exclusive
            shape.RequestNewShape(shapeData[shapeIndex]);
        }
    }
}


Well the first thing Id suggest is add debug messages, and debug and follow what your code is doing it will almost certainly lead you to whats going on

Followed that advice of @BugFinder and added debug messages EVERYWHERE. Literally. Every line of code had one. Didn't help at all. Raged. Deleted all the shapes and just pasted them back. Bug fixed. ¯_(ツ)_/¯.
